# How can output all products for different productFlavors and buildTypes?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I defined two **buildTypes** and two **productFlavors**,but when I run the app,it just output two apks,not four apks,and I see in **Build variants**,I can select only one build variant for each module.So how can I build all products apks?Anyone can teach me,thanks!

**build.gradle:**

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}

productFlavors{
    arm{
        applicationId = "com.demo.falvor1"
    }
    x86{
        applicationId = "com.demo.falvor2"
    }
}
```

**build variants:**
[image]

Comment: Using the command line: `./gradlew assemble`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the "Gradle project" tab (bottom-right), then select "Execute gradle task" (the fourth button at the top).

It will open a dialog to enter a command, then you just need to type `assemble`.